# Is there a Linux keylogger which records the timestamp at which every input was given? If not how would one go about doing this?

Tags: logs, software-rec, input

In the end I want it so that I have a list of time steps which record, at each time step, what key was pressed (or what was the last key pressed in the given interval). I'm not sure such software exists so something which simply records the timestamp to an appropriate temporal resolution would work.

Answer (score 2):

[logkeys](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys) should fit your needs. The manual is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/logkeys.8.html).